# windows server 2003 static route disapper

Tags: windows-server-2003, static-routes

I have a strange issue here. I have a windows server 2003 R2 which need to manually add some routes. I used route add -p command but found that the routes still be removed automaticly even the servers in keep alive without reboot. I suppose that windows 2003 would automaticlly remove static route not be used for 48 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on this key to make sure it is not read-only: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\PersistentRoutes